# jquery rotate, drag and resize

Tags: jquery, draggable

I am working on a project in which i want to drag, rotate and resize images.
This is my first jquery project and so far things are working ok.
Trough stackoverflow i found the plugin [jqueryrotate](http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/) which handles the rotation.

The problem is that i now have an image which i can drag around and rotate but when i try to resize a rotated image, i get some funny results. The resizing after the rotation seems off.

HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryrotate.googlecode.com/files/jQueryRotate.2.1.js"></script>
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>    

<img id="resizableImage0" class="resize" width="100px" height="100px" alt="tile0" src="http://www.elaxtro.com/images/demo.png">
<img id="resizableImage1" class="resize" width="100px" height="100px" alt="tile1" src="http://www.specialized.com/OA_MEDIA/2009/bikes/9397-20_demo8_2_ano_blue_d.jpg">
```

jQuery

```
window.zindex = 30;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".resize").resizable();

    $(".resize").parent().draggable({
        stack: "div"
    });

    $(".resize").rotate({
        bind: {
            dblclick: function() {
                // get current
                var currentAngle = $(this).get(0).Wilq32.PhotoEffect._angle;
                var newAngle = currentAngle + 90;
                $(this).rotate(newAngle);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

The fiddle should make things clear.
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U64se/20/)

Doubleclicking rotates an image 90 degrees :)

Is there anyone who can help me with this.

Thank you in advance.

Edit: fixed the resizer in the fiddle example
Please note that the problem is best visible if you rotate once so that the image is 90 degrees rotated. After this try to resize.

The problem does not occur when an image is 0 degrees or 180 degrees rotated

Comment: just found out that my resizer doesn't work in my fiddle example but it does my own files. I will try to fix this.
thank you Rory for updating my post.

Comment: Did you find some help? I'm looking for the same, need to build a collage builder tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you did with `draggable()`, you must use `rotate()` on the parent `div`.

```
$(".resize").resizable({handles: 'ne, se, sw, nw'});
$(".resize").parent().draggable({
    stack: "div"
});
$(".resize").rotate({
    bind: {
        dblclick: function() {
            $(this).data('angle', $(this).data('angle')+90);
            var w = $(this).css('width');
            $(this).parent().rotate({ animateTo: $(this).data('angle')}).css({width: $(this).css('height'), height: w});

        }
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/U64se/163/ (wow 163…)